# PyQtGraph disable mouse wheel, but leave other functions of the mouse untouched

Tags: python, pyqt5, mouseevent, pyqtgraph, viewbox

I have a pyqtgraph.ViewBox widget with an image in it. The mouse is enabled, so I can select a rectangle on the image and it will be zoomed. But there is an unwanted feature, the zooming occurs on the mouse wheel scrolling aswell.

How can I disable the mouse wheel only, and leave the rest as is?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import pyqtgraph as pg
import cv2


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pg.setConfigOption('imageAxisOrder', 'row-major')
        pg.setConfigOption('leftButtonPan', False)  # if False, then dragging the left mouse button draws a rectangle
    
        self.grid = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        self.top_left = self.grid.addViewBox(row=1, col=1)

        image = cv2.imread('/path/to/your/image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        self.image_item = pg.ImageItem()
        self.image_item.setImage(image)
        self.top_left.addItem(self.image_item)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.grid)


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install an event filter on the ViewBox and catch the mouse wheel event, in this case `QEvent.GraphicsSceneWheel`.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent
import pyqtgraph as pg
import cv2


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pg.setConfigOption('imageAxisOrder', 'row-major')
        pg.setConfigOption('leftButtonPan', False)  # if False, then dragging the left mouse button draws a rectangle
    
        self.grid = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        self.top_left = self.grid.addViewBox(row=1, col=1)
        self.top_left.installEventFilter(self)

        image = cv2.imread('/path/to/your/image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        self.image_item = pg.ImageItem()
        self.image_item.setImage(image)
        self.top_left.addItem(self.image_item)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.grid)

    def eventFilter(self, watched, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.GraphicsSceneWheel:
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(watched, event)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is way simpler than the accepted answer. Use setMouseEnabled on the ViewBox:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import pyqtgraph as pg
import cv2


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pg.setConfigOption('imageAxisOrder', 'row-major')
        pg.setConfigOption('leftButtonPan', False)  # if False, then dragging the left mouse button draws a rectangle

        self.grid = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        self.top_left = self.grid.addViewBox(row=1, col=1)
        self.top_left.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=False)  # <--- Add this line

        image = cv2.imread('/path/to/your/image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        self.image_item = pg.ImageItem()
        self.image_item.setImage(image)
        self.top_left.addItem(self.image_item)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.grid)


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it didn't work, so the accepted answer is still the better solution for me.

Comment: I am using pyqtgraph-0.11.0. When you say it did not work, what does that mean? I am not sure if I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Not working means the mouse wheel zoom is not ignored. The question was about ignoring the wheel, and the wheel only, and the accepted solution does the trick.